# Corpus Distillation

Tags: tools, fuzzing

Anyone know of any tools or scripts that can help in [corpus distillation](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2011/08/fuzzing-at-scale.html) ? I know of [Peach Minset](http://old.peachfuzzer.com/v3/minset.html), but not other than that. Appreciate if anyone could share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote [minblox](https://github.com/ea/minblox) for that exact purpose. It relies on DynamoRIO. Compared to minset which uses pin tool, there isn't much of a difference. Tho I think actual set minimization part works faster than minset.

Minblox tool is comprised of two parts.

- A DynamoRIO instrumentation part (libbbcoverage) tasked with recording all basic block executed during application execution.
- minblox.py - Python script that runs the DynamoRIO instrumentation and analyzes the log files to minimize the sample set.

Though, do bear in mind that I've only tested this for a specific case I needed it, so your mileage might vary.

Comment: Why you didn't use the DrCov tool and then parse the (text format) log files? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Sweet Thanks 0xea! Will definitely have a look at that :)

Comment: What about using Valgrind with Call grind to look at basic blocks? Have either of you tried this method?

Comment: @joxeankoret no particular reason, wrote it as a test...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is nothing like this public. However, you can use [DrCov](http://dynamorio.org/docs/page_drcov.html) and do yourself the same thing as Minset does and even more powerful things. Indeed, I commonly use this DynamoRIO's tool, DrCov, for doing this exact same thing and others.

Comment: Thanks joxean! ps. shout out from Syscan '14. Great talk :)